# Regex to test if there's a word appeared exactly 2 times

Tags: regex, pcre

Given a string, test if there's a word appeared exactly two times

| Input | Pass |
| --- | --- |
| `apple banana pineapple` | No |
| `apple banana apple pineapple` | Yes |
| `apple banana banana pineapple` | Yes |
| `apple banana apple pineapple apple` | No |
| `apple banana apple banana` | Yes |
| `apple banana banana apple pineapple apple` | Yes |

I tried something like this but didn't work :(

```regex
^.*(\b\w+\b)(?:(?!\b\1\b).)*\b\1\b(?:(?!\b\1\b).)*$
```

Any suggestions? I'm using pcre.

Comment: What if there is a pair of two exact words and three other exact words?

Comment: @JvdV It should pass, as long as there's a word appeared exactly 2 times

Comment: @HaoWu That seems like a very counterintuitive edge case to me, one which your sample data also does not cover.  You might want to just form a collection of words in your application language and do the check there, rather than using regex.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sorry, I added the edge case to the sample input.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: BTW, is it PCRE2 or PCRE?

Comment: @Nick I'm using PHP 7.2.1, so I think it's PCRE, not PCRE2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get next word. Stop if it contained exactly 2 times. Loop.

`^(?*.*?\b(\w+)\b)(?>.*?\b\1\b){2}(?!.*\b\1\b)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/upfKOm/1)

Comment: ++ for teaching me this new feature of **Non atomic Positive Lookahead** but this is specific to PCRE2 (PHP > 7.3) and is **not Perl-compatible**.

Comment: ++ Never heard of it either. Maybe I should upgrade my PHP for this.

Answer (score 3):

Using PyPi `regex` module that allows dynamic length lookbehind:

```sh
\b(\w+)\b(?<!\b\1\b.*\b\1\b)(?:(?!\b\1\b).)*?\b\1\b(?!.*\b\1\b)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bjkMzW/1)

**Code:**

```sh
>>> import regex as re
>>> arr = ["apple banana pineapple", "apple banana apple pineapple", "apple banana banana pineapple",
... "apple banana apple pineapple apple", "apple banana apple banana", "apple banana banana apple pineapple apple"]
>>> reg = re.compile(r'\b(\w+)\b(?<!\b\1\b.*\b\1\b)(?:(?!\b\1\b).)*?\b\1\b(?!.*\b\1\b)')
>>> for i in arr: print (i, '=>', reg.findall(i))
...
apple banana pineapple => []
apple banana apple pineapple => ['apple']
apple banana banana pineapple => ['banana']
apple banana apple pineapple apple => []
apple banana apple banana => ['apple']
apple banana banana apple pineapple apple => ['banana']
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `\b(\w+)\b`: Match a word with word boundaries and capture in group #1
- `(?<!\b\1\b.*\b\1\b)`: Dynamic length lookbehind to assert that we have don't another instance of same word before this word
- `(?:(?!\b\1\b).)*?\b\1\b`: Match another instance of same word while ensuring we don't match same word in between 2 repeats
- `(?!.*\b\1\b)`: Finally make there is no other instance of this word ahead of us, thus making sure there are only 2 instances

---

**Earlier Answer:**

This regex with a negative lookahead may work:

```sh
^(?!.*?\b(\w+)\b(?:.*\b\1\b){2}).*?\b(\w+)\b.*\b\2\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gKrrBC/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?!`: Negative lookbehind start

  - `.*?`: Match 0 or more of any characters
  - `\b(\w+)\b`: Match and capture a word
    - `(?:.*\b\1\b){2}`: If same word is present at least twice
- `)`: Negative lookbehind end
- `.*?`: Match 0 or more of any characters
- `\b(\w+)\b`: Match and capture a word in capture group #2
- `.*\b\2\b`: Make sure same word is present at least once more

Comment: @Jvdv: Added an answer using `regex` module as it requires variable length lookbehind.

Comment: Isn't `(?!...)` negative look-**ahead**?

Comment: `(?!..)` is negative lookahead but `(?<!...)` is a negative lookbehind.

Comment: OP is using PHP, not Python